# fleqn modifies vertical spacing in document

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am almost done writing an article, and wanted to change the alignment of figures and equations using the fleqn option in the documentclass environment. However, after implementing the change, the vertical spacing of paragraphs seems to slightly change, and many things that I had fine tuned are now ruined.

What is causing this problem, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Could you please provide an MWE?

Comment: @JouleV That's slightly problematic, since the difference seems to be only a line at times. The document is 26 pages long, so the full effect seems to show only in this situation. I'll try to come up with something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the default centred layout tex can use a shorter vertical space if the equation does not overlap. If the text is

```
para para para para para para para para
para para para
                  a=b
```

then a smaller vertical space (`\abovedisplayshortskip`) is used than if it was

```
para para para para para para para para
para para para para para para

                 a=b
```

when `\abovedisplayskip` is used.

If you left align the equation it always overlaps the last line of the preceding paragraph so the short skip is never used.

```
para para para para para para para para
para para para

a=b
```

Comment: I see. And it would definitely look awkward with the smaller spacing and left alignment. Thanks!